# Extract a sub-array by using a distinguished row symbol # in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have some command lines stored in a text file, and I separated them into different groups by using distinguished row symbol, say #step1 for group one, #step2 for group two,etc. My question is how I'm able to extract each group and execute each command line by using #step* as an input argument.

steps text file:

```
#step1
command line 1
command line 2
command line 3
...
#step2
command line 4
command line 5
command line 6
...
```

How to create a function somewhere in my code context, which can do something like:

```
execSteps "#step1"
```

or is there another way to organize my steps text file?

Any ideas?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This isn't an array at all unless you want to store all the steps in memory rather than parsing through the file every time. Which... would actually be reasonable, but it isn't part of the specification whether to do that or not.

Comment: The reason why I'd like to do this is each time when I install new version of Gentoo Linux to my computer, package names maintain the same, but the USE flags always change. I decided to store package names which I want to install to a text file and separated them into different groups so that I'm able to accept USE flags as input parameters and don't have to worry about the procedure and type 'emerge packagename' again and again. Even if I've stored the whole procedure to an executable script file, it's boring to update USE flags when new version Gentoo stage and portage are available.

Comment: Rest of emerging packages are some command lines like 'cp', 'mkdir', 'rc-update', and they also had to be mixed among those emerging steps, which means they had been separated into different steps stored in a text file as emerging steps did. This thread is mainly about how to deal with these grouped command lines.

Comment: Hmm. If you want to execute those groups inside the current shell, you might want to `eval "$(getSteps "$@")"` rather than using `getSteps "$@" | sh -`, which executes the steps in a separate child shell.

Comment: Would you please suggest what would happen if these steps are not in the same shell? I used `chroot` to run `emerge package` remotely. Does it matter?

Comment: The details matter -- I can't give you an answer from only the one line above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
getSteps() {
  local running=0
  while read -r line; do
    if (( running )); then
      if [[ $line = "#"* ]]; then
        return
      else
        printf '%s\n' "$line"
      fi
    else
      [[ $line = "#"$1 ]] && running=1
    fi
  done <stepFile
}

execSteps() {
  getSteps "$@" | sh -
}
```

Then, you can print the code for a step by running `getSteps step1`, or execute that code with `execSteps step1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Charles! It worked for me very well.

Comment: Hi, Charles, if I'd like to take one step further, say in the function getSteps() at line `printf '%s\n' "$line"`, separate this step into two substeps, substep1: execute `emerge --pretend $line(packagename)` , collect USE flags manually, and set make.conf, substep2: execute `emerge $line(packagename)`. My further question is how to execute emerge inside this while loop? Don't worry about other stuff. Thank you again.

Comment: The comment above is too dense to be unambiguously understood. I'd suggest asking a new question focused specifically on the place you're having trouble, with the parts you do understand factored out.

Comment: @TaoWang, please add your own answer with your extended version of the code -- the edit you suggested was somewhat too expansive to include here, but I'd be glad to upvote it as a separate answer. (Yes, I treat all comments as tags; that was intentional, because the question wasn't clear enough about what did and did not constitute a tag).

Comment: @MikeWise, please consider being more cautious about which edit suggestions you approve. The change you approved suggested code with a great deal of functionality which had nothing to do with the actual question, and other adjustments it made were related to unstated (as opposed to explicit) requirements.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want to define a shell "module". Save it as `mymodule`:

```
step1 () {
    command line 1
    command line 2
    command line 3
}

step2 () {
    command line 4
    command line 5
    command line 6
}
```

To use it, simply source it from your script, and call the desired function

```
. mymodule
# Run step 1
step1

# Run step 2
```